# issue with fixed menu

Tags: css

I have a header and menu bar that I have fixed to stay at the top of the page, so when ever someone scrolls on the page or something the menu and header are right there at hand.

My question is in regards to the content/body of the page. I have tried using absolute positioning coming down 150 px from the top (the menu and header are 125px), and I want 25px between the two at the top of the page.

However, it instead positions to the left side of the page, but I want it to be centered in a fluid manner.

I have also tried just giving a top margin of 150px, but that didn't work for some reason.

How can I center it horizontally, but have it at least 150px from the top vertically?

Here is some of the code.

If you need something even more visual, you can look on my test site http://sunnahmatch.com for what's going on right now.

**EDIT** I have the vertical spacing down. Now if I could just figure out how to center it? :/

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0;
    background-color:#333;
    }
#body_container{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    padding:15px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:70%;
    }
#left_container{
    float: left;
    width: 63%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background-color:#069;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
    }
#right_container{
    float:left;
    width: 31%;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#069;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
    }
.column_left_tmpl{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
.column_right_tmpl{
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 10px;
    font-family: GeosansLight;
    font-size: 16px;#59C169
    }
.title {
    width:100% auto;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
.spacer{
    height:5px;
    }
#menu_container{
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;}    
</style>

<body>
<div id="menu_container">
<?php include_once "pages/header.php" ?>
</div>
<div id="body_container">
    <div id="left_container">
      <div class="column_left_tmpl">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
      &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;
        </div>
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
    <div class="column_left_tmpl">&quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;
    </div>   
    </div>
    <div id="right_container">
      <div class="column_right_tmpl">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
      &quot;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&quot;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<?php include_once "pages/footer.php" ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>There is nothing wrong with your CSS, your document is just missing a Doctype. Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your document. Or `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">` for XHTML 1.1.</strike>

An additional advice is to wrap the whole thing in a `html` tag as well, and put the `style` tag inside a `head` tag

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/* more stuff here */
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You have a `style` element outside the `head` tag. Start with putting that inside the head tag. Then change the CSS for `body_container`: remove `position:absolute` and change the margin to `margin: 150px auto 0 auto;`.

```
#body_container{
 /* position:absolute; */ /* removed */
 top:150px;
 padding:15px;
 /*margin:0 auto;*/
 margin: 150px auto 0 auto; /* changed */
 width:70%;
}
```

Comment: No, I have the full doctype, html, body etc tags, I just didn't include them as I thought it'd be repetitive and assumed, :/

Comment: Agree, but funny aspect is that if you open your website in Opera or FF and then choose "view source" it doesn't show them. I figured that it might have something to do with the `style` tag within the body. Please see my update. (In IE's "view source" you can in fact see your doctype and html etc.)

Comment: The fix worked for the most part, except I have a 150px margin around the whole thing, I just want it on the top though.

Comment: hmm, its showing up on google chrome in the source, I fixed the position of the style tags, so perhaps it should show up now in the source, it is on google chrome now. Good catch though!

Comment: yup the `margin: 150px auto 0 auto` is a shorthand notation for `margin: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];` so it will make 150px top margin, left and right auto, and bottom 0. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting a specific width to your *div* and set *margin-left* and *margin-right* to *auto*. This will automatically center that *div*.

Try following this tutorial, it is looking at the same problem.
[Centering a DIV](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml)

Comment: that won't work with a fluid div at all? My content is at 70% width and I'd personally like to keep it at that if possible

Comment: Bazzz is using almost the same in his answer:  *margin: 150px auto 0 auto;* <br /> This means *margin-top:150px; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto;* So yes it would work :)

Comment: Oh awesome, I get it, it goes clockwise, top right bottom left, that's great to know!

Comment: `margin: auto` doesn't work on elements that are positioned absolute. It doesn't make any sense to position something absolute and then have it calculate automagically what the margin should be. The OP needed to remove the `position: absolute` as well, for the `margin:auto` to work.

Comment: Yes,  you are correct. Position:absolute; should not be used together with auto margins.

Answer (score 0):

.... and `<html>` and `<head>` and `<title>`

Thought about using a validation service?

Comment: I use w3c validation, clearly I should be using it before finishing the pages though.